# Is capturing female slaves allowed?

Tags: manu-smriti, war

Manu Smriti [verse 7.96](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200762.html) says:

> rathāśvaṃ hastinaṃ chatraṃ dhanaṃ dhānyaṃ paśūn striyaḥ |
>   sarvadravyāṇi kupyaṃ ca yo yaj jayati tasya tat || 96 ||
>
> Chariots and horses, elephants, umbrellas, wealth, grains, animals,
>   women, all goods and baser metals belong to him who wins them.—(96)

Does women in above verse mean that kings can take female sex slaves?

Comment: No. it's not sanctioned. Only if he wins *all* of them. Winning as you know is different. You can't stand in one place and win a horse. Similarly, without winning a women's heart, how can they be won? And hence the advancement of intelligence to species. Do you know there was a Pralaya in Manu's time exactly for this reason? Interpreting, things literally and causing all freaking confusion. We have to remember that we are no longer monkeys...Particularly with so many reasonable Nobel laureates around ...:-)

Comment: Not for the purpose of sex.

Answer (score 2):

[Apastamba Dharmasutra](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/dharma/apasta2.asp#k13) prohibits to have sex with a women who is not married to him.

> 4. **If a man approaches a woman who had been married before, or was not legally married to him**, or, belongs to a different caste, **they both commit a sin.**

Comment: Are you saying this takes precedence over the Manusmriti verse quoted by the OP?

Comment: @iruvar many manusmriti shlokas are interplotation. This shloka is not present in Critical edition of Manusmriti compiled by Surendra Kumar.

Comment: Thanks. In that case your response to the question should lead with that assertion in regard to OP's verse. As things stand, you are presenting a verse that contradicts the OP's with no justification as to why your verse should have primacy over the OP's

Comment: @iruvar an Arya cannot possess female sex slaves because adultery/prostitution is against Arya Dharma. If it is sanctioned by Manu, then the practice must be mentioned in other Puranas & ItihAsa-s. But it is not. Royal families as mentioned in MAhAbhArata had slaves but never for sexual pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

'Women' in that verse probably means wives of dead kings and soldiers who were made slaves later.

Speaking on Satī, P. V. Kane [says](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.280927/page/n671/mode/2up):

> *Satī* was not in historic times a practice imposed by priests or men on unwilling women. It somehow grew and it is improper to say that men imposed it on women. It may be that examples of *satī* occurred because of the force of popular sentiment. It was first confined to kings and nobles, because the lot of the wives of conquered kings and warriors was most miserable in all countries as well as in India. **Vengeance** for the truculence of their husbands **was wreaked on the poor wives by carrying them as captives and making them work as slaves**.
>
> **Manu ([VII.96](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200762.html)) allows a soldier to retain women (probably 'slaves') conquered by him along with other booty.** When queen Yaśomati narrates to her son Harṣa the great honour and glory that was hers during the reign of her husband king Prabhākaravardhana, she refers to the fact that the wives of the enemies defeated by her husband waved chowries over her. From kings the practice spread among brāhmaṇas, though as shown above, several smṛtikāras disapproved of the practice among brāhmaṇa wives. Once it took root learned commentators and digest writers were found to support it with arguments and promises of future rewards...Manu [IV.178](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200283.html) asks people to do whatever their forefathers did.

Comment: There is a story in mahabharata in whivh husband of a dasi kills a master for trying to have forceful sex with his wife dasi do you have it's link.

Comment: That reminds me of Kichaka-Draupadi story in Virata Parva. Why don't you ask a separate question about it with the identification-request tag? @Anisha